# Disable NTLM authentication to all pages in MVC site EXCEPT for one page (/controller/ action)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, ntlm

We are planning to deploy an MVC website to prod and we would like to DISABLE NTLM authentication to all pages but ONE. The intended behavior is that when any non-logged in/ anonymous user tries to access any page he will be thrown to the login page, but if he tries to access a specific page, let's say

http://samplewebsite.org/SweetHome/Authenticate/SSO

The NTLM authentication will kick in.

Can anyone teach me how?

Thanks in advance.